# Accessing Variables by multiple threads in web application

Tags: c#, multithreading, webforms

I am running a web Form where I call a new thread on a button press to execute an Rdotnet snippet of code ( I needed the thread because the current thread kept sending stack overload errors ).

In the Rdotnet function , I have it access a global class variable and put data into it. Once the function completes and the button submit function is over I try to access that global class on another button click ( separate button ), however it is empty. I assume that the thread ends so all data in it ends to, so I tried returning the class and putting it into the global variable in the buttonclick function itself,same result.

I need help.

```
public partial class BTForm : Page
{


    List<DirectorDetail> Details = new List<DirectorDetail>();
    BindingList<string> Test = new BindingList<string>();
    List<string> Line = new List<string>();
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    WebDetails BTlibrary;




    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    List<string> Months = new List<string>();
    List<string> Year = new List<string>();
    BTBill Billfile = new BTBill();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            addMonth();
            addyear();
            foreach (var x in Months)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(x);
            }

            foreach (var y in Year)
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(y);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            ListBox4.DataSource = Test;
            ListBox4.DataBind();

        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            Console.Write(x);
        }



    }

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread current = Thread.CurrentThread;

        WebDetails BTlibrary2 =BTlibrary;

        Thread t = new Thread(() => { BTlibrary2 = processes(BTlibrary2); }, 2500000);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();


        BTlibrary = BTlibrary2;
       // Thread.Sleep(10000);



    }



    public WebDetails processes(WebDetails library)
    {

        if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
        {
            string location = @"C:/BTBill/" + FileUpLoad1.FileName;
            Billfile.Tablename = FileUpLoad1.FileName;

            try

            {
                Billfile.Month = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Billfile.Year = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Billfile.Filename = Cleaning.PathCleaning(location);

                Billfile.Limit = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
                string fpath = Billfile.Month + " " + Billfile.Year + " Query " + "Limit -£ " + Billfile.Limit + "\\";
                string filename = Billfile.Month + " " + Billfile.Year + " Query " + "Limit -£ " + Billfile.Limit;

                Billfile.Savelocation = "//lonvmfs01/commonwealth_Data/BT BILL Alert/" + filename;
                Billfile.Sfilename = "//lonvmfs01/commonwealth_Data/BT BILL Alert/" + filename;

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Error1.Text = "Please Select Month and year\nERROR : " + x;
            }


            FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"C:\BTBill\" + FileUpLoad1.FileName);



            library = Executable.executable(Billfile);


            //  FileUpLoad1.
            //  = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "No File Uploaded.";
        }


        DataFrame Director = library.Director;
        DataFrame bill = library.Query;
        DataFrame limit = library.Btlim;


        int colcount = Director.RowCount;

        for (int x = 0; x < colcount; x++)
        {
            string cost_centre = Director[x, 0].ToString();
            string director = Director[x, 1].ToString();
            string email_address = Director[x, 2].ToString();
            double total = SendMail.calculatetotal(bill, limit, cost_centre);

            if (total > 0)
            {
                Line.Add(x + " )\t" + cost_centre + "\t" + director + "\t\t" + email_address + "\t" + total);
                Test.Add(x + " )\t" + cost_centre + "\t" + director + "\t\t" + email_address + "\t" + total);
            }


        }

        ListBox4.DataSource = Test;
        ListBox4.DataBind();


        //foreach (var x in getline().ToArray())
        // {
        //    ListBox4.Items.Add(x);
        // }

        //  ListBox4.DataBind();


        return library;
    }

    protected void Sendmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataFrame Director = BTlibrary.Director;
        DataFrame bill = BTlibrary.Query;
        DataFrame limit = BTlibrary.Btlim;


        string test;
        foreach (Object selecteditem in ListBox4.GetSelectedIndices() )
        {

            test = ListBox4.Items[(int)selecteditem].Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);

            test = test.Substring(0, 1);
            output.Add(test);
        }

        List<int> index = new List<int>();

        for (int y = 0; y < output.Count; y++)
        {
            index.Add(Convert.ToInt32(output[y]));
        }


        for (int y = 0; y < index.Count; y++)
        {
            DirectorDetail temp = new DirectorDetail();
            temp.cost_centre = Director[index[y], 0].ToString();
            temp.director = Director[index[y], 1].ToString();
            temp.email_address = Director[index[y], 2].ToString();

            for (int count = 0; count < limit.RowCount; count++)
            {
                if (limit[count, 0].ToString() == temp.cost_centre)
                {
                    temp.limit = limit[count, 1].ToString();
                }
            }

            Details.Add(temp);

        }


        SendMail.Mailing(BTlibrary.Query, BTlibrary.Deplist, BTlibrary.Btlim, BTlibrary.Bill, Details);

        //Session["Details"] = Details;

        //  this.Close();

    }









    private void addyear()
    {

        DateTime time = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

        int baseyear = time.Year - 3;
        for (int x = baseyear; x < (baseyear + 10); x++)
        {
            Year.Add(x.ToString());
        }

    }



    // returns the list of years 
    public List<string> getYear()
    {
        return Year;
    }

    // returns the list of months 
    public List<String> getMonth()
    {
        return Months;
    }

    //adds months to a list
    private void addMonth()
    {


        Months.Add("January");
        Months.Add("February");
        Months.Add("March");
        Months.Add("April");
        Months.Add("May");
        Months.Add("June");
        Months.Add("July");
        Months.Add("August");
        Months.Add("September");
        Months.Add("October");
        Months.Add("November");
        Months.Add("December");


    }



    public List<string> getline()
    {
        return Line;
    }

}





 public static WebDetails executable(BTBill bill)
    {



        StartupParameter rinit = new StartupParameter();
        rinit.Quiet = true;
        rinit.RHome = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4\";
        rinit.Home = @"C:\R";


        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();

        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance(null,true,rinit);
        // engine.Initialize();

        //install and make connection to Postgres
        // engine.Evaluate("install.packages('RPostgreSQL') \n install.packages('gridExtra')");

        engine.Evaluate("require('RPostgreSQL')" + "\n" +
                        "pw <- {'admin'}" + "\n" +
                        "drv <- RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()" + "\n" +
                        "drv <- dbDriver('PostgreSQL')" +"\n"+
                        "con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = 'postgres'," +"\n"+
                        "host = 'localhost', port = 5432," +"\n"+
                        "user = 'postgres', password = pw)");

        engine.Evaluate("postgresmfile<- dbGetQuery(con,'select * from masterfile')" + "\n" +
                        "Contact <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from contact')"+"\n"+
                        "btlim<- dbGetQuery(con, ' select * from bt_departmentlimit')"+"\n"+
                        "dbDisconnect(con)");

        engine.Evaluate("BTBill = read.csv(file<-'"+bill.Filename+"', header=TRUE, sep=',',skip=1)");




        // building dataframes and queries
        DataFrame BTBill = engine.Evaluate("BTBill").AsDataFrame(); 
        DataFrame MasterFile = engine.Evaluate("postgresmfile").AsDataFrame();
        DataFrame BTLim = engine.Evaluate("btlim").AsDataFrame();
        DataFrame Contact= engine.Evaluate("Contact ").AsDataFrame(); 
        DataFrame Query = engine.Evaluate("Merged <- merge(BTBill,postgresmfile,by.x='SERVICE.NO',by.y = 'service_number')" + "\n"+ "Merged_2 <- merge(Merged,Contact,by.x='cost_centre',by.y='cost_centre') " + "\n"+
           "query <- Merged_2[c('SERVICE.NO','username','cost_centre','job_post','USAGE.CHARGES','TOTAL.COST','USAGE.START.DATE','USAGE.END.DATE','director','email_address')]").AsDataFrame();
        DataFrame Merge2 = engine.Evaluate("Merged_2").AsDataFrame();

        DataFrame maillist = engine.Evaluate("data.frame(query)" +"\n"+
                "test <-subset(query, TOTAL.COST >= "+bill.Limit+ ", select = c(SERVICE.NO,username,cost_centre,job_post, TOTAL.COST, USAGE.START.DATE, USAGE.END.DATE,director,email_address,USAGE.CHARGES))").AsDataFrame();
        DataFrame DepList = engine.Evaluate("x<-test[c('cost_centre','director','email_address')]" + "\n" +
                                          "ux<-unique(x) ").AsDataFrame();

        DataFrame DepList2=engine.Evaluate("y <-query[c('cost_centre', 'director', 'email_address')]" + "\n" +
                                          "uy<-unique(y) ").AsDataFrame();

        engine.Evaluate("dir.create(file.path('" + bill.Savelocation + "'))");

        //creating pdf files for each department head 



        engine.Evaluate("write.csv(Merged_2, file = '" + bill.Savelocation + "/MasterFile.csv');");
        for (int count = 0; count < DepList.RowCount; count++)
        {
            DataFrame temp = engine.Evaluate("data.frame(query);" +
               "test2 <-subset(query, USAGE.CHARGES >= " + bill.Limit + " & cost_centre=='"+DepList[count,0]+"', select = c(SERVICE.NO,username,cost_centre,job_post, USAGE.CHARGES, USAGE.START.DATE, USAGE.END.DATE,director,email_address))").AsDataFrame();
            engine.Evaluate("library(gridExtra);");



          engine.Evaluate("pdf('" + bill.Sfilename +"/"+ DepList[count, 0] + ".pdf', height=20, width=20);"  );

            try
            {
                engine.Evaluate("grid.table(test2); dev.off() ;");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }


        SendMailForm form = new SendMailForm();


        WebDetails web = new WebDetails(DepList2, Query, BTLim);
        web.Deplist = DepList;
        web.Bill = bill;

        engine.Evaluate("write.csv(test, file = '" + bill.Savelocation + "/Users over threshold.csv')");

        engine.Dispose();

        return web;



        // form.Director=DepList2;
        //form.bill = Query;
        //form.limit = BTLim;

        List<DirectorDetail> output = form.Details;









        SendMail.Mailing(Query, DepList,BTLim, bill,output);
        // to filter by department 
        // DataFrame maillist = engine.Evaluate("data.frame(query)" + "\n" + 
        //         "test <-subset(query, TOTAL.COST >= " + bill.Limit + "& Cost.Centre=='"+bill.Dep+"', select = c(SERVICE.NO, User.Name, Cost.Centre, ROLE.JOB.POST, TOTAL.COST, USAGE.START.DATE, USAGE.END.DATE,DIRECTOR,EMAIL.ADDRESS))").AsDataFrame();


        //engine.Evaluate("install.package('dplyr')");








    }
}
```

}

Comment: The variable i am referring to is WebDetails BTlibrary; which should be visible by all functions in the form behindcode (which it is). My problem is, after the Submit_Click function accesses it and changes it and ends, the Sendmail function tries to access it, but it sees it as null.

Comment: The fundamental issue here is that web requests are stateless. Over multiple requests you aren't dealing with a single instance of `BTForm`. Each button click = new instance of `BTForm`. As such, you likely want to assign a value of `BTLibrary` in `Page_Load` so you know it is **always** set.

Comment: @mjwills that worked! thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

It seems my problem turned out to be unrelated to variable sharing through threads, but instead to deal with the way button click instances worked.

long story short, in order to share a variable between two event instances, the easiest way to do it is through Sessions.

I needed to put the BTlibrary in a session and access it in the second button click event for it to get the value saved from the previous.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread current = Thread.CurrentThread;

        WebDetails BTlibrary2 =BTlibrary;

        Thread t = new Thread(() => { BTlibrary2 = processes(BTlibrary2); }, 2500000);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();


        Session["BTLib"] = BTlibrary2;

       // Thread.Sleep(10000);



    }

protected void Sendmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DirectorDetail> Details = new List<DirectorDetail>();

        BTlibrary = (WebDetails) Session["BTLib"];
```

this worked

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).